# java client/server using tls, CA signed cert

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

I have to implement a server - client program that uses TLS protocol. I used openssl and I follow the instractions given in this link https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/ 
cause this is exactly what I want to do (I don't want self-signed certificates for client or server). Then I used keytool to create keystores and I converted the files properly in order to save them to keystore.
I tried to use this code on the server part:

```
private void setupClientKeyStore() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException 
    {
    clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
    clientKeyStore.load( new FileInputStream( "C:/Users/Claire/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PrivaChatPUCR/src/privachatpucr/clientpub.jks" ),
                       "password".toCharArray() );
    }

    private void setupServerKeystore() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
    InputStream keyStoreResource = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Claire/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PrivaChatPUCR/src/privachatpucr/plainserver.jks");
    char[] keyStorePassphrase = "password".toCharArray();
    serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    serverKeyStore.load(keyStoreResource, keyStorePassphrase);

    }

    private void setupSSLContext() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException 
    {
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
    tmf.init( clientKeyStore );

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
    kmf.init( serverKeyStore, "password".toCharArray() );

    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
    sslContext.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(),tmf.getTrustManagers(),secureRandom );
    }

and this code on the client side:

 private void setupServerKeystore() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
    serverKeyStore.load( new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Claire/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PrivaChatPUCR/src/privachatpucr/serverpub.jks"), 
                        "password".toCharArray() );
  } 
   private void setupClientKeyStore() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
    clientKeyStore.load( new FileInputStream( "C:/Users/Claire/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PrivaChatPUCR/src/privachatpucr/plainclient.jks" ),
                       "password".toCharArray() );
  }
   private void setupSSLContext() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
    tmf.init( serverKeyStore );

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
    kmf.init( clientKeyStore, "password".toCharArray() );

    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
    sslContext.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(),
                     tmf.getTrustManagers(),
                     secureRandom );
  }
```

but this code until now works only for self-signed certificates and not with mine. Do I have to use other code? 
Also am I done with TLS? Are the messages encrypted?
I have to save this program in  jar files (one for server and one for client)  but when I do this and run it on another pc of course it cannnot run properly cause it doesn't have the certs anymore in the appropriate path. Is there another way to store the files in order to work from any pc?

Sorry but I am new in java and cryptography. I would appreciate any answers